# Parsing JSON File in Java until attribute has changed value

Tags: java, json

I want to parse a JSON File until the attribute "updated" is changed to true. I am running a python script at the same time which updates the JSON and sets "updated" to true. I only want to continue my java program, if the JSON is updated. This is what my code looks like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 src/main/java/metis.py");
boolean pythonExecuted = false;
String s = String.valueOf(Paths.get("./json/", "output.json"));
JSONParser jsonParser1 = new JSONParser();
while (!pythonExecuted){
    FileReader reader1 = new FileReader(s);
    JSONObject obj1 = (JSONObject) jsonParser1.parse(reader1);
    boolean updated = (boolean) obj1.get("updated");
    if (updated){
         pythonExecuted = true;
    }
}
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "updated": false
}
```

I get this exception: Exception in thread "main" Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
I know this happens because I read the file too often. What could be a solution?

Comment: I assume you're doing this to allow the Java program to know when the Python has completed some task. If so, it may be easier to simply write out an empty file at a per-defined location and just check for its existence. Once the Python program has written the file then the Java program will know by inquiring the OS..? // Otherwise trying to interleave file reads between the two programs is going to be rough without trampling one another. // If you do need to pass some JSON based data, use the solution I mention and just write it to the file.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. That may be difficult. Since I am doing this process multiple times in my java program. Each time I call the python script and wait for it write something in the JSON. I currently put my program for 1000ms to sleep, but I would prefer a better solution. So I need some solution to check multiple times within the program if the python script is finished.

Comment: If the Python program does not exit after it has completed the task, then in the Java program just check for the "flag file" existence in a loop every `x` seconds. // If the Python program exits after completing the task then why not just start the Python script in a sub-process and `.join` on it (block until it exits)? You'll instantaneously know when it has completed the task without having to check "manually".